# Купить продукты или купить продуктов?

Tags: падежи, управление, родительный-или-винительный

Купить продукты или купить продуктов?

Речь не идет об определенных продуктах. Следовало бы ставить *продукты* в родительном падеже, однако на практике преобладает винительный (в Нацкорпусе 44:13). Как вы это объясните? "Просто так сложилось"?

Comment: "А я так люблю крабы."

Answer (score 1):

Действительно,  сочетание "купить продукты" (В.п.) применяется чаще, в то же время мы  используем Р.п. для  конкретных продуктов:  *Купи себе что-нибудь на завтрак, чаю купи, хлеба… Купи хлеба у крестьян…*

Р.п. обозначает  часть предмета (не весь же хлеб мы купим у крестьян, а какое-то количество). При этом  мы часто указываем, сколько именно купить: Сходи, пожалуйста, в магазин, купи хлеба полкило... Эта количественная оценка присутствует в форме Р.п., которую мы привыкли употреблять.

Для продуктов же Р.п. подходит в меньшей степени, так как это **собирательное** существительное, и у нас нет понятия "продукты —  часть продуктов". Словом "продукты" можно обозначить  продуктовый набор любого объема.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, собирательные существительные (например,  листва, дубняк, осинник, детвора) имеют форму только единственного числа. Разве *продукты* — собирательное?

Comment: Продукт/продукты не относится к собирательным существительным с точки зрения грамматики, но по смыслу он может иметь собирательное значение: ПРОДУКТЫ, 2. обычно мн.: продукты,  Предметы питания, съестные припасы.

Comment: У Вас это звучит как некое правило: для собирательных существительных и их смысловых аналогов В. п. подходит больше, чем Р. п. (*принеси листву* лучше, чем *принеси листвы*). Это личное мнение или оно опирается на какой-то источник?

Comment: С вещественными существительными ведь наоборот: принеси молока.

Comment: Это мое личное понимание значения Р.п. (количественно-разделительного, или партитивного). В этом случае действие переходит на предмет, но охватывает его не целиком, а частично: принеси хлеба, молока. Соответственно, Р.п. используется для  существительных,  из которых можно выделить часть, в том числе это касается вещественных существительных..  Можно не использовать слово "собирательное", если оно вам не нравится. Просто если взять часть продуктов, то эта часть будет также называться "продукты". Принцип делимости здесь не действует. Поэтому грамматика - это единственный источник, других нет.

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять. Часть молока тоже называется молоком, не так ли?

Comment: Так, конечно.  Но используя Р.п.,  вы не предлагаете выпить всё молоко, которое есть в доме, или купить всё молоко, которое есть в магазине. Р.п. -  наша привычная речь: купи пакет (немного) молока, выпей стакан (немного) чаю. А вот купи немного продуктов - так не говорят. Потому что молоко, хлеб - это однородная масса, а продукты состоят из множества разных составляющих.

Comment: Но ведь мы говорим: купи молока, выпей чаю. Почему "купи продуктов" не аналогично? "Немного продуктов" тоже не запрещено (Мать оставила денег из расчета рубль в день, десять по-тогдашнему, и немного продуктов. [Руслан Киреев. Картошка // Библиотека «Огонек», 1989] )

Comment: Не запрещено, конечно, разные бывают ситуации.  Но Вы сами обозначили частотность: на практике преобладает винительный падеж  (в Нацкорпусе 44:13). Я объяснила в ответе, почему преобладает.

Answer (score 0):

44:13 — статистика явно недостаточная, поэтому никаких выводов делать нельзя.

Всё же попытаюсь: ведь гораздо чаще покупают не просто продукты, а те, которые нужны. Поэтому и винительный. Остальным тринадцати, видимо, было все равно что покупать. Такие, естественно, в меньшинстве.